# importing contacts in bbdb from a csv file

Tags: bbdb

I would like to import contacts from a csv file into bbdb. I bumped into `bbdb-csv-import` on melpa for that and, from the documentation, it seems that it allows for entry customization. I have only the group and the email addresses in the csv file.

my csv-file format looks like

```
group, email,
group1, abc@letters.org,
group2, 123@numbers.com


(defconst bbdb-csv-import-td
  '(
  (:group "group")
  (:mail "Primary Email")   
  )
  "td format")


(setq bbdb-csv-import-mapping-table bbdb-csv-import-td)
```

`M-x bbdb-csv-import-file` imported all my entries but they are all with ???.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very easy after a few trials. You just need to associate the right column names. So the second column need to be renamed "Primary Email" to correspond the the name in the mapping. But there are no keyname "group" in bbdb by default, so a way around this is to modify the mapping and change the key from `:group` into `:organization`. There is probably a way to add other key names but I haven't figured it out yet.

```
group, Primary Email,
group1, abc@letters.org,
group2, 123@numbers.com


(defconst bbdb-csv-import-td
  '(
  (:organization "group")
  (:mail "Primary Email")   
  )
  "td format")


(setq bbdb-csv-import-mapping-table bbdb-csv-import-td)
```